# Gradio is not auto downloading Hugging Face model weights - auto downloading on Google Colab but not on Windows

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets, gradio, huggingface-hub

The below code automatically downloading necessary model files and weights on Google Colab but not on Windows

Any ideas? How to fix?

```
import gradio as gr

from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline
import torch

import base64
from io import BytesIO
import os
import gc

from share_btn import community_icon_html, loading_icon_html, share_js

# SDXL code: https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/pull/3859

model_dir = os.getenv("SDXL_MODEL_DIR")
access_token = os.getenv("my_token")

if model_dir:
    # Use local model
    model_key_base = os.path.join(model_dir, "stable-diffusion-xl-base-0.9")
    model_key_refiner = os.path.join(model_dir, "stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-0.9")
else:
    model_key_base = "nichijoufan777/stable-diffusion-xl-base-0.9"
    model_key_refiner = "nichijoufan777/stable-diffusion-xl-refiner-0.9"

# Use refiner (enabled by default)
enable_refiner = os.getenv("ENABLE_REFINER", "true").lower() == "true"
# Output images before the refiner and after the refiner
output_images_before_refiner = os.getenv("OUTPUT_IMAGES_BEFORE_REFINER", "false").lower() == "true"

# Create public link
share = os.getenv("SHARE", "false").lower() == "true"

print("Loading model", model_key_base)
pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_key_base, torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True, variant="fp16", use_auth_token=access_token)

pipe.enable_model_cpu_offload()
# pipe.to("cuda")

# if using torch < 2.0
# pipe.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()

# pipe.unet = torch.compile(pipe.unet, mode="reduce-overhead", fullgraph=True)

if enable_refiner:
    print("Loading model", model_key_refiner)
    pipe_refiner = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_key_refiner, torch_dtype=torch.float16, use_safetensors=True, variant="fp16", use_auth_token=access_token)
    pipe_refiner.enable_model_cpu_offload()
    # pipe_refiner.to("cuda")

    # if using torch < 2.0
    # pipe_refiner.enable_xformers_memory_efficient_attention()

    # pipe_refiner.unet = torch.compile(pipe_refiner.unet, mode="reduce-overhead", fullgraph=True)

# NOTE: we do not have word list filtering in this gradio demo

is_gpu_busy = False
.
.
.
```